# Is there a way to detect query changes using Vue-Router and successfully get new data?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am simply making an asynchronous request to get data about a MLB player but am failing to get new data by manually changing the query parameters in the URL.  When I use watch, the from and the to are the same for some reason upon debugging with Vue dev tools.  However, all works well when I manually click a link to navigate routes as the from and the to correctly represent the from and the to routes.

PitcherForm.vue

```js
export default {
  name: "PitcherForm",
  components: {
    PlayerForm,
  },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.handleSubmit({ firstName: this.$route.query.firstName, lastName: this.$route.query.lastName });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit: function(formValues) {
      // this.$store.dispatch("fetchPlayer", { formValues, router: this.$router, player: "pitching" });
      this.$store
        .dispatch("fetchPlayer", { formValues, player: "pitching" })
        .then((promiseObject) => {
          console.log(promiseObject)
          this.$router.push({
            // name: 'PitcherData',
            path: "pitching/player",
            query: {
              firstName: promiseObject.firstName,
              lastName: promiseObject.lastName,
            },
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
```

//store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VuexPersist from 'vuex-persist';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

// VuexPersist stuff
const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'vuex',
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin],
  state: {
    playerStats: []
  },
  // mutations, getters, excluded for convenience
  actions: {
   
    fetchPlayer({ commit }, data) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let firstName = data.formValues.firstName.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
        let lastName = data.formValues.lastName.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
  
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/${data.player}/player`,
        {
          params: {
            first: firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1),
            last: lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.slice(1),
          },
        }).then(response => {
            commit('setPlayers', response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

        resolve({firstName, lastName});
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your route watcher calls a function which changes the route.  Seems like circular logic

Comment: Thanks.  How would you go about loading the player's results in a different route via manually changing the url then?  Basically, it works for when the user inputs a player's information via a form and upon an action that submits an axios get request, another component matched by the player's first and last name is loaded.

Comment: `handleSubmit` makes sense to call from form submit, and to change the route with a new query. But it's not clear why it would then be called again in the watcher. It's understandable that a watch would do something when the query changes, but not change the query again